# How to check if two variables from different function are equals?

Tags: swift

I'm new to Xcode and Swift but I'm trying my best :) 
I need a little help. I have wrote this code so far... but I have an issue and I don't know how to solve it... 
Well, my issue is that I cannot check if two variables are equal or not. To be more precise, I'd like to check if "fileAudio" number is equal to the photo number shown in the app.

I'd also need some help to show two random pictures (leftImage and rightImage) and the "playSound" button to be linked to one of them. At this moment... I only could make it linked to the leftImage.

```
var soundFiles: [String] = [
    "s0",
    "s1",
    "s2",
    "s3",
    "s4",
    "s5",
    "s6",
    "s7",
    "s8",
    "s9"
]

var images1: [UIImage] = [

    UIImage(named: "foto0.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "foto1.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "foto2.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "foto3.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "foto4.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "foto5.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "foto6.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "foto7.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "foto8.png")!
]

var images2: [UIImage] = [
    UIImage(named: "foto0.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "foto1.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "foto2.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "foto3.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "foto4.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "foto5.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "foto6.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "foto7.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "foto8.png")!
]

var happySad: [UIImage] = [
    UIImage(named: "sad.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "happy.png")!
    ]

var currentImageIndex = 0
var currentImage2Index = 0


var player: AVAudioPlayer!
var ran1:Int = 0
var ran2:Int = 0


@IBOutlet weak var leftImage: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var rightImage: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var sh: UIImageView!


@IBAction func playSound(_ sender: Any) {

    let fileaudio:String = "s"+String(ran1)
    let soundFilePath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileaudio, withExtension: ".m4a")!
    player = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundFilePath)
    player.prepareToPlay()
    player.play()
}
  @IBAction func nextImages(_ sender: Any) {
    ran1 = Int(arc4random_uniform(7) + 1)
    ran2 = Int(arc4random_uniform(6) + 2)

    let imageName1:String = "foto"+String(ran1)
    leftImage.image = UIImage.init(named: imageName1)

    let imageName2:String = "foto"+String(ran2)
    rightImage.image = UIImage.init(named: imageName2)

    leftImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.view.addSubview(leftImage)
    let gesture1 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.singleTap1))
    leftImage.addGestureRecognizer(gesture1)

    sh.image = UIImage(named: "question")
    rightImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.view.addSubview(rightImage)
    let gesture2 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.singleTap2))
    rightImage.addGestureRecognizer(gesture2)
 }

func singleTap1() {

    if currentImageIndex == ran1 {
        print("\(currentImageIndex)")
        sh.image = UIImage(named: "happy.png")
    } else {
        print("\(currentImageIndex)")
        sh.image = UIImage(named: "sad.png")
    }
}

func singleTap2() {
  if ran1 == ran2 {
        sh.image = UIImage(named: "happy.png")
    } else {
        sh.image = UIImage(named: "sad.png")
    }

}
```

thank you, Radu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should generate a random number from 0 to 1 to represent the two buttons. One `singleTap:` function should handle both cases.

```
fileprivate var leftRightNum: Int!

@IBAction func nextImages(_ sender: Any) {
    ran1 = Int(arc4random_uniform(7) + 1)
    ran2 = Int(arc4random_uniform(6) + 2)

    let imageName1:String = "foto"+String(ran1)
    leftImage.image = UIImage.init(named: imageName1)

    let imageName2:String = "foto"+String(ran2)
    rightImage.image = UIImage.init(named: imageName2)

    leftImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.view.addSubview(leftImage)
    let gesture1 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.singleTap(_:)))
    leftImage.addGestureRecognizer(gesture1)

    sh.image = UIImage(named: "question")
    rightImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.view.addSubview(rightImage)
    let gesture2 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.singleTap(_:)))
    rightImage.addGestureRecognizer(gesture2)

    leftRightNum = Int(arc4random_uniform(2))
 }

@IBAction func playSound(_ sender: Any) {
    let fileaudio:String = "s"+String(leftRightNum == 0 ? ran1 : ran2)
    let soundFilePath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileaudio, withExtension: ".m4a")!
    player = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundFilePath)
    player.prepareToPlay()
    player.play()
}

func singleTap(_ recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    if (recognizer.view == leftImage && leftRightNum == 0) || (recognizer.view == rightImage && leftRightNum == 1) {
        sh.image = UIImage(named: "happy.png")
    } else {
        sh.image = UIImage(named: "sad.png")
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to generate a random number in playSound. I have two images ( left and right) and a button, playSound. I need to link the playSound button to one of the two images (not always the same) When I click the playSound button, I hear an audio, example dog barking. Then the use has to choose which image represents the sound (left or right). Could you help me doing that? please :)

Comment: thank you so much! It's working like a charm :D
Can I ask you how can I make it display already the 2 images as I open the app? At now when I open the app..I see only playSound button and nextImages button. And if I tap on playSound as I open the app..it crashes..and the error is "expected to found nil..." thanks again!!!

Comment: You should call the `nextImages` function in viewDidLoad.